# Replace nested for loops in printing long output

Tags: r

I have the data below:

```
Kd1Par<-as.matrix(c(1,2,3))
Kd2Par<-as.matrix(c(1,2,3))
```

and the algorithm which uses nested for loops:

```
for (i in 1:length(Kd1Par)){
  for (j in 1:length(Kd2Par)){

    Kd1 <- Kd1Par[i]
    Kd2 <- Kd2Par[j]
    print(c(Kd1 = Kd1Par[i], Kd2 = Kd2Par[j]))
    myDose[i, j] <- 10
    print(c(Dose = myDose[i,j]))

  }}
```

in order to give me this output :

```
Kd1 Kd2 
  1   1 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  1   2 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  1   3 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  2   1 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  2   2 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  2   3 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  3   1 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  3   2 
Dose 
  10 
Kd1 Kd2 
  3   3 
Dose 
  10
```

The problem is that my real dataset is too big and the `for` loops is an efficient method but very slow so I would like to replace it with a method that gives me exactly the same result as above. Note that `myDose[i, j] <- 10` is not always 10 in my real project but comes from another calculation that gives every time another result but here I set is as 10 in order to simplify the problem.

```
# my app in case it makes more sense to understand the issue
library(deSolve)
library(caTools)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(minpack.lm)
library(reshape2)
library(pracma)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # fluidRow(title='Schematic of Two Memb Bound Target ',
  #          img(src='twoMemBound.png',width='100%')),

  plotOutput('PKPlot'),

  actionButton(inputId = "click",
               label = "Run"),
  fluidRow(

    column(4,
           h6("Dosing regimen Parameters",style = "color:red",align="center"),
           sliderInput("nIter", label = h6("Contour Smoothness"),
                       min = 2, max = 15, value = 3),
           sliderInput("reqMinInh", label = h6("Minimum Inhibition"),
                       min = 10, max = 100, value = 90),
           sliderInput("nd", label = h6("Number of Doses"),
                       min = 3, max = 100, value = 4),
           # sliderInput("endTime", label = h6("Simulation time in Days"),
           #             min = 0, max = 500, value = 77),
           sliderInput("tau", label = h6("Dosing interval in Days"),
                       min = 0.1, max = 50, value = 7),
           sliderInput("BW", label = h6("Bodyweight in Kg"),
                       min = 60, max = 100, value = 70)
    ),
    column(4, 
           h6("Drug Parameters",style = "color:red",align="center"),
           sliderInput("CL", label = h6("Drug Clearance (L/day)"),
                       min = 0.1, max = 0.3, value = 0.24),
           sliderInput("Vp", label = h6("Volume of Plasma Comp (L)"),
                       min = 0.1, max = 3, value = 3),
           sliderInput("Kon1", label = h6("Drug Affinity for Target 1 (1/(nmol/L)/day)"),
                       min = 0.1, max = 2, value = 1.3824),
           sliderInput("Kon2", label = h6("Drug Affinity for Target 2 (1/(nmol/L)/day)"),
                       min = 0.1, max = 2, value = 1.3824),
           sliderInput("MW", label = h6("Molecular Weight in da"),
                       min = 50e3, max = 200e3, value = 150e3)
           # sliderInput("Vph", label = h6("Volume of Peripheral Comp (L)"),
           #             min = 0.1, max = 5, value = 3.1),          
           # sliderInput("Vt", label = h6("Volume of Tissue Comp (L)"),
           #             min = 0.1, max = 0.2, value = 0.192),
           # sliderInput("k_01", label = h6("First Order Absorption Rate (1/day)"),
           #             min = 0.1, max = 2, value = 1),

    ),
    column(4,
           h6("Target Parameters",style = "color:red",align="center"),
           sliderInput("R01", label = h6("Baseline Conc of Target 1 (nmol/L)"),
                       min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 0.1),
           sliderInput("R02", label = h6("Baseline Conc of Target 2 (nmol/L)"),
                       min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 0.1),
           sliderInput("HL1", label = h6("Half-life of Target 1 (min)"),
                       min = 0.01, max = 100, value = 100),
           sliderInput("HL2", label = h6("Half-life of Target 2 (min)"),
                       min = 0.01, max = 100, value = 100)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  v <- reactiveValues(doPlot = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    v$doPlot <- input$click
  })

  output$PKPlot <- renderPlot({

    if (v$doPlot == FALSE) return()

    isolate({
      reqMinInh <- input$reqMinInh # (%) Min inhibition of Target
      nd <- input$nd # Number of doses
      tau <- input$tau
      endTime <- (nd+1)*tau
      BW <- input$BW
      MW <- input$MW
      nIter <- input$nIter

      Kd1Par <- logspace(-1.98,1.698,n = nIter)
      Kd2Par <- logspace(-1.98,1.698,n = nIter)

      myDose <- matrix(c(0), nrow= length(Kd1Par), ncol = length(Kd2Par))

      Kon_m1 <- input$Kon1 # (1/(nmol/L)/day)
      Kon_m2 <- input$Kon2 # (1/(nmol/L)/day)
      Base1 <- input$R01
      Base2 <- input$R02
      HL1 <- input$HL1
      HL2 <- input$HL2
      Kint_m1  <- 0.693*60*24/HL1 # (1/day)
      Kint_m2  <- 0.693*60*24/HL2 # (1/day)
      Kdeg_m1  <- Kint_m1 # (1/day)
      Kdeg_m2  <- Kint_m2 # (1/day)
      Ksyn_m1  <- Base1*Kdeg_m1 # (nmol/L/day)
      Ksyn_m2  <- Base2*Kdeg_m2 # (nmol/L/day)


      Vp  <- input$Vp # (L) Ref: Vaishali et al. 2015
      Vph  <- 3.1 # (L)  Ref: Tiwari et al. 2016
      Vt  <- 0.192 # (L) Spleen, Ref: Davis et al. 1993
      k_01  <- 1 # (1/day)  Ref: Leonid Gibiansky
      CL  <- input$CL # (L/day)  Ref: Leonid Gibiansky
      K_el  <- CL/Vp # (1/day)
      k_pph  <- 0.186 # (1/day) Ref: Tiwari et al. 2016
      k_php  <- 0.184 # (1/day) Ref: Tiwari et al. 2016
      Ktp  <-  0.26 # (1/day)
      Kpt  <- 0.004992 # (1/day)



      times <- seq(from = 0, to = endTime, by =0.1)
      yInit <- c(Ap = 0.0, Dp = 0.0, Dt = 0.0, 
                 M1 = Base1, M2 = Base2,
                 DtM1 = 0.0, DtM2 = 0.0, DtM1M2 = 0.0, Dph = 0.0) 

      derivs_pk1 <- function(t, y, parms) {
        with(as.list(c(y,parms)),{
          dAp_dt <- -k_01*Ap
          dDp_dt <- k_01*Ap/Vp -K_el*Dp +Vt/Vp*Ktp*Dt -Kpt*Dp +Vph/Vp*k_php*Dph -k_pph*Dp
          dDt_dt <- Vp/Vt*Kpt*Dp -Ktp*Dt -Kon_m1*Dt*M1 +Koff_m1*DtM1 -Kon_m2*Dt*M2 +Koff_m2*DtM2
          dM1_dt <- Ksyn_m1 -Kdeg_m1*M1 -Kon_m1*Dt*M1 +Koff_m1*DtM1 -Kon_m1*DtM2*M1 +Koff_m1*DtM1M2
          dM2_dt <- Ksyn_m2 -Kdeg_m2*M2 -Kon_m2*Dt*M2 +Koff_m2*DtM2 -Kon_m2*DtM1*M2 +Koff_m2*DtM1M2
          dDtM1_dt <- -Kint_m1*DtM1 -Koff_m1*DtM1 +Kon_m1*Dt*M1 -Kon_m2*DtM1*M2 +Koff_m2*DtM1M2
          dDtM2_dt <- -Kint_m2*DtM2 -Koff_m2*DtM2 +Kon_m2*Dt*M2 -Kon_m1*DtM2*M1 +Koff_m1*DtM1M2
          dDtM1M2_dt <- Kon_m2*DtM1*M2 -Koff_m2*DtM1M2 +Kon_m1*DtM2*M1 -Koff_m1*DtM1M2 -Kint_m1*DtM1M2 -Kint_m2*DtM1M2
          dDph_dt <- Vp/Vph*k_pph*Dp - k_php*Dph
          list(c(dAp_dt,dDp_dt,dDt_dt,dM1_dt,dM2_dt,dDtM1_dt,dDtM2_dt,dDtM1M2_dt,dDph_dt))
        })
      }


      ssq <- function(parmsToOptm){

        Dose <- parmsToOptm[1]

        injectEvents <- data.frame(var = "Ap",
                                   time = seq(0,tau*(nd-1),tau),
                                   value = Dose*1e6*BW/MW, # (nmol)
                                   method = "add")
        pars_pk1 <- c()

        qss_pk10<-ode(times = times, y = yInit, func =derivs_pk1, parms = pars_pk1,events = list(data = injectEvents))
        qss_pk1<- data.frame(qss_pk10)

        temp <- qss_pk1[qss_pk1$time>tau*(nd-2)&qss_pk1$time<tau*(nd-1),]
        inh1 <- (1-temp$M1/Base1)*100
        inh2 <- (1-temp$M2/Base2)*100
        if(min(inh1,inh2) %in% inh1) {
          currMinInh <- inh1
        } else {currMinInh <-inh2}

        ssqres = currMinInh - reqMinInh
        return(ssqres)

      }


      for (i in 1:length(Kd1Par)){
        for (j in 1:length(Kd2Par)){

          Kd1 <- Kd1Par[i]
          Kd2 <- Kd2Par[j]
          print(c(Kd1 = Kd1Par[i], Kd2 = Kd2Par[j]))
          Koff_m1 <- Kon_m1*Kd1 # (1/day)
          Koff_m2 = Kon_m2*Kd2 # (1/day)

          # Initial guess
          parmsToOptm <- c(10)

          fitval<-nls.lm(par=parmsToOptm,fn=ssq,control = nls.lm.control(ftol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps),
                                                                         ptol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), gtol = 0, diag = list(), epsfcn = parmsToOptm[1]/100,
                                                                         factor = 100, maxfev = integer(), maxiter = 50, nprint = 0))
          myDose[i, j] <- c(coef(fitval))
          print(c(Dose = myDose[i,j]))
        }
      }

      KdMat <- expand.grid(Kd1Par,Kd2Par)
      temp1  <- melt(myDose)
      myDoseFormat <- data.frame(Kd1=KdMat$Var1, Kd2 = KdMat$Var2, Dose = temp1$value)

      minDose <- myDoseFormat[myDoseFormat$Dose == min(myDoseFormat$Dose),]


      Kd1 <- minDose$Kd1
      Kd2 <- minDose$Kd2
      Koff_m1 <- Kon_m1*Kd1 # (1/day)
      Koff_m2 = Kon_m2*Kd2 # (1/day)

      Dose <- minDose$Dose

      injectEvents <- data.frame(var = "Ap",
                                 time = seq(0,tau*(nd-1),tau),
                                 value = Dose*1e6*BW/MW, # (nmol)
                                 method = "add")
      pars_pk1 <- c()

      qss_pk10<-ode(times = times, y = yInit, func =derivs_pk1, parms = pars_pk1,events = list(data = injectEvents))
      qss_pk1<- data.frame(qss_pk10)


      mytheme_grey <- theme_grey(base_size=18)+theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, colour="grey60"))

      p1 <- ggplot(myDoseFormat, aes(x = Kd1, y = Kd2, z = Dose)) +
        geom_raster(aes(fill = Dose), interpolate=T) +
        scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() + 
        labs(title = "Contours of dose (mg/kg)", x="Target-1 Kd (nM)",y="Target-2 Kd (nM)") +
        guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "Dose (mg/kg)")) +
        theme(legend.position=c(0.9, 0.75))

      p2 <- ggplot(qss_pk1,aes(x=time/7)) +
        geom_line(aes(y=Dp)) +
        labs(x="Time (weeks)",y="Drug Conc (nmol/L)") +
        mytheme_grey

      cols <- c("Target 1" ="red", "Target 2" = "blue")
      p3 <- ggplot(qss_pk1,aes(x=time/7)) +
        geom_line(aes(y=M1, colour = "Target 1"), size = 1.5, linetype = 1) +
        geom_line(aes(y=M2, colour = "Target 2"), size = 1.5, linetype = 2) +
        labs(x="Time (weeks)",y="Target Conc (nmol/L)") +
        scale_colour_manual(name = "Targets", values = cols)+
        mytheme_grey

      p4 <- ggplot(qss_pk1,aes(x=time/7)) +
        geom_line(aes(y= (1-M1/Base1)*100, colour = "Target 1"), size = 1.5, linetype = 1) +
        geom_line(aes(y= (1-M2/Base2)*100, colour = "Target 2"), size = 1.5, linetype = 2) +
        labs(x="Time (weeks)",y="Target Occupancy (%)") +
        scale_colour_manual(name = "Targets", values = cols)+
        mytheme_grey


      ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,labels=c("A","B","C","D"), ncol=4,nrow=1)


    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it to print out like this?  Why not output a data frame with the columns `Kd1` `Kd2` and `Dose`?

Comment: Would it be helpful to post my whole app here since it would make more sence for you if you would run it.?

Comment: Actually I would love to see what you propose and maybe that will help me solve my problem.In case this dataframe is created faster

Comment: can Kd1 and Kd2 be interpreted as numeric row and column indixes?

Comment: actually I use them as values in lines 175-176 of my app

Comment: they can be interpreted like these when creating the myDose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a loop?

```
# Create a data frame of all combinations
df <- expand.grid(Kd1Par = c(1,2,3),  Kd2Par = c(1,2,3))

# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# If function is vectorised
df %>% 
  mutate(Dose = MyFunction(Kd1Par, Kd2Par))

# If function is not vectorised
df %>% 
  mutate(Dose = map2_dbl(Kd1Par, Kd2Par, MyFunction))
```

Here, I create all possible combinations of `Kd1Par` and `Kd2Par` and then run the dose function, which I called `MyFunction`.

For example,

```
# Example dose function
MyFunction <- function(x, y)x + y
```

would give something like

```
#   Kd1Par Kd2Par Dose
# 1      1      1    2
# 2      2      1    3
# 3      3      1    4
# 4      1      2    3
# 5      2      2    4
# 6      3      2    5
# 7      1      3    4
# 8      2      3    5
# 9      3      3    6
```

Comment: I really like your approach but I think it  may be adjusted more in lines 169-187 of my app. I posted it to make it more clear.

Comment: I will consider your answer valid since it covers the initial Q but I would really like to have your insight on the app code.

Comment: @firmo23 That's a lot of uncommented code to wade through and I don't really know Shiny, so it's difficult to say. But, if you're essentially solving your model with different model parameters, I think you could rewrite it to use the non-vectorised version of my solution. You'd need to have a function that took the parameters, solved the model, and returned the solution. That function could then be run by `map2`.